# Combustion without hydrogen

Tags: combustion

Is there any fuels without hydrogen that will combust. My friend believes there might be and do to my experience I have never heard of one. Please explain and if u can show a balanced equation of this combustion.

Comment: Other then base element's suck as sulphate.

Comment: And carbon and iron and magnesium and... Why would elements be special? Would steel count than? Your friend is quite wrong...

Comment: Cyanogen seems to be an example ($\ce{(CN)2 + O2 -> 2CO + N2}$). Check [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01098a517), it briefly discusses the reaction. Despite not being open access, the first page is available - and it contains only one page...

Comment: Prior to electricity, most households were heated by burning solid fuel known as coal (which is basically carbon). Does that count?

Comment: Fuels like coal are made out of carbon hydrogen chains

Answer (score 1):

A combustion reaction is classified as a reaction between a fuel and oxygen to produce energy. The reaction: 2CO(g) + O2(g) = 2CO2(g) fulfills this definition, is exothermic, and does not use hydrogen.

Comment: So does the reaction C + O2 -> CO2, i.e. the combustion of coke (or graphite or diamonds).